# Узнать, есть ли в классе "рабочие" методы

Tags: php

Есть класс с методами

```
class Test {

    public function m1() {

    }

    public function m2() {

    }
}
```

Есть наследник:

```
class randomName extends Test {
    /*
    public function m1() {

    }

    public function m2() {

    }
    */

    public function m111() {

    }

    public function m222() {

    }
}
```

Прошу заметить, что в наследнике сейчас закоменчены методы родителя.

Вопрос: можно ли как-то проверить, что те самые методы не активны? Я хочу это для того, чтобы если не активны (закоменчены или вообще отсутсвуют), т вызвать методы `m111` или `m222` соответствнно.

Классы рефлексии, `is_callable` и `method_exists` не помогают это выявить достоверно. Либо я не понимаю как.

Comment: А какой тут будет юз кейс? В смысле почему нельзя просто определить методы m1 и м2? и написа в них то, что написано в м111 и м222?

Comment: @Ипатьев если m1 и m2 будут раскоменчены, то предполагается по умолчанию использование именно этих методов. То есть логика может быть разная прописана в этих всех методах

Comment: А вам точно классы нужны? Все эти закомментированные методы очень мало походят на ООП

Comment: ерунда какая-то по моему. сделайте какую нить настройку, константу или еще чего нить, которая будет определять условие поведения, и впишите в стандартный `m1()`  в начало что `if(self::cond) return $this->m11()`, или что-то в этом роде. Пытаться понять закоментированы методы в классе или нет, и на этом основании строить логику приложения попахивает бредом.

Comment: Не знаю зачем вам это но есть ключевое слово `static` вызывающее метод из текущего класса. Если метод в классе не определен - вызывается родительский и далее по цепочке.

Comment: @teran ну если перформулировать, то я ищу не закоменченые методы, а не переопределённые. Так корректнее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел путь решения на [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17663347/6138795).

```
$reflector = new \ReflectionMethod($ob, 'createTable');
$isProto = ($reflector->getDeclaringClass()->getName() !== get_class($ob));
```

Суть в чем: проверяется наличие метода `createTable` в объекте  `$ob`, далее сравнивается имя класса, в котором объявлен метод `$reflector->getDeclaringClass()->getName()` и имя текущего объекта `get_class($ob)`.  Если они совпадают - то значит метод был переопределен, если нет - значит нет (значит например был закоментирован или просто не переопределен)